# How to fetch JMSMessageID from JMS response

Tags: mule

I tried to find a way but was unsuccessful to fetch JMSMessageID that comes as response from JMS after sending a message to a queue. Would someone please help me with it? Thanks.
(this question is similar to [Extract JMSMessageID on response from JMS Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879389/extract-jmsmessageid-on-response-from-jms-queue), but I could neither comment nor re-request on the same question, so creating a new question following the suggestion)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a response transformer java class to do this. Be sure to put a objectToJms transformer before this.

```
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.mule.api.MuleMessage;
import org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException;
import org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope;
import org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer;

public class ExtractJmsMessageIdTransformer extends AbstractMessageTransformer {

    @Override
    public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding) throws TransformerException {

         if (message.getPayload() instanceof Message) {
             Message jmsMessage = (Message) message.getPayload();
             String jmsMessageId = null;
             try {

                 jmsMessageId = jmsMessage.getJMSMessageID();
                 logger.info("Found JmsMessage as payload. jmsMessageId = " + jmsMessageId)
             } catch (final JMSException e) {
                 throw new TransformerException(this, e);
             }
         }

        return message;
    }
```

}

**EDIT1 Per Comments**

Your not defining the ExtractJmsMessageIdTransformer class on your response transformers. In your mule-config.xml add the following

```
<custom-transformer class="mypack.ExtractJmsMessageIdTransformer" name="extractJmsMessageIdTransformer"/>

<jms:object-to-jmsmessage-transformer name="objectToJms" />
```

then define your JMS queue like this

```
<jms:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" disableTemporaryReplyToDestinations="true" queue="sample" connector-ref="JMS"
                           doc:name="JMS" transformer-refs="objectToJms" responseTransformer-refs="objectToJms extractJmsMessageIdTransformer"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="#[message.outboundProperties]"/>
```

Comment: I get null ID, is it logging from input? <br>
My XML is as below:
'<set-payload value="Welcome to Mule" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
 <jms:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queue="sample" connector-ref="JMS" doc:name="JMS" responseTransformer-refs="Object_to_JMSMessage"/>
<custom-transformer class="mypack.ExtractJmsMessageIdTransformer" doc:name="Java"/> <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="#[message.outboundProperties]"/>' <br>
Log shows below output:
mypack.ExtractJmsMessageIdTransformer: Found JmsMessage as payload. jmsMessageId = null.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry for my bad formatting response, I'm still getting tuned to. Please check my above code and suggest where it needs the corrections.

Comment: Basically, either I use one-way or request-response exchange pattern with TIBCO EMS, I would just get the NullPayload, hence no JMSMessageID. Are we missing something from the configuration end of Mule flow or just with the TIBCO EMS? I cannot claim its with TIBCO EMS since a basic TIBCO JMS flow will instantly get the messageid in response schema. Also tried with a sample java code, I was successful in getting the actual sent message's JMSMessageID, just Mule flow is unable to get it. Any other suggestions from the configuration / code end please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Someone suggested to use disableTemporaryReplyToDestinations="true" for jms:outbound-endpoint, it didn't work. This looks like related to temporary destinations, so sounds not much useful.

Comment: Thanks for getting back again. It looks like the MuleMessage which gets populated as a response from EMS doesn't have these properties, so trying this logic was not much helpful either. I just printed the message and payload in the transformer and below was the output.
'ObjectMessage={ Header={ JMSMessageID={null} JMSDestination={null} JMSReplyTo={null} JMSDeliveryMode={PERSISTENT} JMSRedelivered={false} JMSCorrelationID={null} JMSType={null} JMSTimestamp={0} JMSDeliveryTime={0} JMSExpiration={0} JMSPriority={4} } Properties={ MULE_SESSION={big-id-here} } Object={{NullPayload}} }'

Comment: Above was the payload. Problem sounds to me like some communication gap between the way TIBCO EMS expects/responds and the way Mule talks with it. I guess we are missing something in the request where Mule is not able to request EMS to respond back with JMSHeaders. Using disableTemporaryReplyToDestinations="true" is making this worst, I am not hearing back any response at all from EMS, so lets ignore it.Got any other ideas please let me know. Meanwhile, I will try to see how a simple Java code is getting this ID back easily and it if could give us any clues. Appreciate all your help yet again!

Comment: I'm not too sure about TIBCO EMS as i've never used it but for my communication with JMS queues you need to define a <jms:custom-connector/> and then reference the connector name on the queues as a parameter, connector-ref="jmsConnectorNameHere" see https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/tibco-ems-integration for JMS connector help but I suspect you've already done this.